# Real analysis - continuity of functions involving linear maps

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

Let $A: B(0, 1) \subset \Bbb R^{n} \to L(\Bbb R^{n} , \Bbb R^{k} )$ be continuous and suppose that
$$
\exists  α > 0\text{ such that }\|A(0)h\| \ge \alpha \|h\|\quad \forall h \in\Bbb R^n.
$$ Prove that
$$
\exists \delta > 0\text{ such that }\|A(x)h\| \ge\frac{ 1}{2} \alpha\|h\| \quad \forall x \in B(0, \delta)\text{ and }\forall  h \in\Bbb R^n.
$$
**My work**. I have already shown that $\|A^{-1}x\|\ge\|x\|/\|A\|_\text{op}$

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is a continuous map, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $r>0$ such that $\forall\,x\in B(0,r):\,\lVert A(0)-A(x)\rVert_{op}\leq \varepsilon$ (just the definition of continuity at $0\in B(0,1)$).

[Just for clarity, the operator norm of $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^k)$  is defined as $\lVert T\rVert_{op}:=\sup_{\lVert h\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}=1}\lVert Th\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^k} $, which I am pretty sure is what you are using in your question.]

Since we have this nice bound on the operator norm, for any $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$ \forall\,x\in B_r(0):\,\lVert A(0)h-A(x)h\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^k} \leq \varepsilon \lVert h\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,. $$
The point of this is that now you know  that you can (over the entire ball $B_r(0)$) make $A(x)h$ as close to $A(0)h$ as you want (determined by $\varepsilon \lVert h\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n} $). All that remains is to choose $\varepsilon$ in terms of $\alpha$ to complete the problem.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!